# Show that the homomorph image of an abelian group is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

Since $G$ is abelian, we have that:

$$ab = ba \implies \phi(ab) = \phi(ba) \implies \phi(a)\phi(b) = \phi(b)\phi(a)$$

Am I rigth?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Correct. You could also observe that by the first isomorphism theorem, the image of $\phi$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $G$, hence it is abelian.